# Angular DI executing after NGRX createEffect() initialization

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ngrx

I have an ngrx effect class that I'm migrating to a new repo that is suddenly having issues with DI during unit testing. The effects class is simplified below:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

import {
  MyService,
} from '../../../myservice';

import * as MyActions from '../actions/my.actions';

@Injectable()
export class MyEffects {
  fetchManyStuffs$;

 fetchSingleStuff$ = createEffect(() => {
    console.log('create effect 1', !!this.actions$, !!this.service);
    return of(MyActions.fetchSingleStuffSuccess());
  })

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private service: MyService
  ) {
    console.log('constructor', !!actions$, !!service);

    this.fetchManyStuffs$ = createEffect(() => {
      console.log('create effect 2', !!this.actions$, !!this.service);
      return of(MyActions.fetchManyStuffsSuccess());
    })
  }
}
```

My issue is that the function given to `createEffect()` for `fetchSingleStuff$` is executed before the body of the constructor is, so the DI'd services are undefined. This wasn't an issue in the old repo, and I'm having a hard time determining what changed that would affect `createEffect` executing like this.

Output from new repo:

```
create effect 1 false false <<<<<<<

constructor true true

create effect 2 true true
```

Output from old repo:

```
create effect 1 true true <<<<<<<<

constructor true true

create effect 2 true true
```

Here's the spec test:

```js
describe('MyEffects', () => {
  let effects: MyEffects;
  let actions$: Observable<any>;
  let myService: Mock<MyService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MyEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions$),
        provideMagicalMock(MyService),
      ],
    });

    effects = TestBed.inject(MyEffects);
    myService = TestBed.inject(
      MyService
    ) as Mock<MyService>;
  });

  describe('fetchSingleStuff', () => {
    it('should return fetchSingleStuffSuccess', () => {
      const action = MyActions.fetchSingleStuff();
      const completion = MyActions.fetchSingleStuffSuccess('service-response');

      actions$ = hot('-a', { a: action });
      const response = cold('-b|', { b: 'service-response' });
      const expected = cold('--c', { c: completion });
      companyTypesService.getCompanyTypes.mockReturnValue(response);

      expect(effects.fetchSingleStuff$).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
...
```

Old tsconfigs (sorry, `tsc --showConfig` isn't working for some reason)

```
// tsconfig base options
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "esnext",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,

// tsconfig
    "target": "es2020"

// tsconfig.spec
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["jest", "node"]
```

New tsconfigs

```
// tsconfig base options
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true, <<<<
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,

// tsconfig
    "target": "es2022", <<<<
    "module": "commonjs", <<<<<
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, <<<<<
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitOverride": true, <<<<<
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false, 
    "noImplicitReturns": true, <<<<<
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true, <<<<<
    "declaration": true, <<<<<
    "composite": true, <<<<<
    "allowJs": true, <<<<<
    "esModuleInterop": true <<<<<

// tsconfig.spec
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a related issue on their github page: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/3278.

Changing the target from `ES2022` to `ES2020` resolved the error.